# Computing eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of a path

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Let $A\in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ be the adjacency matrix of a path of length $n$, i.e. having ones on the two off-diagonals, and zeros elsewhere. How does one compute the eigenvalues of this?

I know that the answer is $2 \cos(\frac{\pi k}{n+1})$ for $k=1, \dotsc, n$.

When trying to write down the characteristic polynomial, it becomes quite hard. expanding is not possible. Use recursion might be, but I do not know how to get cosine out of recursion.

So I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have a $n\times n$ tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix of the form:
$$A  = \begin{bmatrix} a & c & & & &   \\ b & a  & c &&\mathbf 0 \\ & b & a & c \\ &&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots& \\ &\mathbf 0&&&& \\ &&&&&&&\end{bmatrix},$$
its eigenvalues are given by the formula:
$$ \lambda_k = a + 2 \sqrt{bc}\cdot \cos\left(\frac{ k\pi}{n+1}\right),\quad k=1,\ldots,n$$

I think [this](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~popov/Math609/Golub_trigiag_eigenvalues.pdf) will help you for your specific case.